# Bartle, Introduction to Real Analysis (2010 4 ed), Section 3.2, Problem 6.b, p 69.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Can somebody explain to me how to compute this limit?

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n + 2}$$

Comment: what would be the limit if you take limit along even numbers???? what would be the limit if you take limit along odd numbers????

Comment: I get it :) 1/n = 0

Comment: Guess & verify.

Comment: Do you mind to write your idea explicitly

Comment: the idea of taking even numbers and odd numbers is to just make sure that you do not afraid of the case that you get alternative positive and negative signs.. Nothing much...

Comment: Well, I compared this to 1/n, limit for which is 0. Now I would have to prove that the limit is in fact 0 by applying the definition of a limit. Is that what you were asking about?

Comment: Yes... Use definition to conclude...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $|\frac{(-1)^n}{n + 2}|=\frac{1}{n + 2}$ and by Archimedean property for every $\varepsilon >0$ there is a positive integer $N$ such that $\frac{1}{N}\le \varepsilon.$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 0 since $|(−1)^n/(n+2)|≤1/n$.

Write out page numbers.